# How to increment the results of a Switch statement in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Currently anytime column a or b has a 1, column "something" shows a "W" and when test fails "something" show an "R" as expected.

My desired outcome would be first row with either column a or b = 1 to show W1 in column "something", second row with a or b = 1 to show W2 and so on.  Basically want to increment the value each time the test passes.  The actual more than 2 tests but I think this should be enough to get a logical answer.  Assume some kind of loop will do it.

switch(
a=1 ,"W",
b=1,"W",
True,"R") as something

Comment: This is a good example of how *not* to ask a question. There are no table definitions, example data, or sample SQL statements of what you have tried. Instead just a rambling para that no one will bother to read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: lol , you and I both read it :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't increment with Switch() function.

You want to assign a sequential identifier to records. Options:

1. build a report and use textbox RunningSum property.
2. DCount() domain aggregate function in query, requires a unique ID field, autonumber should serve
   `SELECT *, DCount("*", "tablename", "ID<" & [ID]) + 1 AS Seq;`
   Include filter and sort criteria as appropriate.
3. VBA code writes sequential value to table

Comment: Thank you.  that answers my question.